# SCCM collection evaluates major version numbers in unexpected way

Tags: update, sccm, query, versioning

Why do SCCM collections based upon the logic `Installed Applications (64).Version is less than "100.0"` not evaluate to `true` for applications of version 99.* and below?

The full WQL query statement is as follows, (linebreaks for legibility)

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client 
from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64 on SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
where SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.DisplayName 
like "Mozilla Firefox%" and SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64.Version < "100.0"
```

Mozilla Firefox recently went from version 99.* to version 100.0, and this has caused  collections to stop evaluating lower versions as "less than" 100.0; there are  stopgaps in place to get around this, but would prefer to better understand why it is occurring and how to remediate it properly.